# Resolving this error: 'React' must be in scope when using JSX

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am using React18.2.0 and I have the error shown below when running my project

[image: React must be in scope error]

I have seen some solutions which suggest if I am using Eslint (which I am), I should disable react scope in the rules. I have as shown in my Eslint config file below but it is not working.

[image: Eslint config file showing react scope off]

Another solution was to add `import React from "react";` This works, however, from the documentation we do not need to include this anymore from React17 upwards. So I do not know why I still have this error.

Any assistance would be appreciated

This is my package.json file

[image: package.json file]

Comment: Add below rules in .eslintrc.js / .eslintrc.json to ignore such errors
 rules: {
    // suppress errors for missing 'import React' in files
   "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    // allow jsx syntax in js files (for next.js project)
   "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }], //should add ".ts" if typescript project
  }

Comment: Are you getting these errors when you `npm start` from command line?

Comment: Yes whenever I run npm start @Kartoos

Comment: @David.E Can you share the minimal source code for `category-preview.components.jsx`? Can you check dependencies section of `package.json` if the react version is correct?

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xorcx) is online sandbox for react17 which might be helpful

Comment: I have @Kartoos

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the following line to your .eslintrc:

```
{
  "extends": ["plugin:react/jsx-runtime"]
}
```

Then only import React once in your top-level file, like App.jsx - and no need to import it anywhere else, unless you need an API like `useEffect` etc.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work.

Comment: worked for me, it removed the exact error